# Правильно ли использовать такие media-запросы?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Сейчас верстаю тестовый сайт, хочу узнать. 
Правильно ли, с точки зрения валидности, использовать например @media screen and (max-width: 800px)?
Или как по другому можно добиться адаптивности не нарушая валидность сайта?

Comment: А какой валидности вы хотите добиться? media запросы не запрещены.

Comment: Валидатор говорит валидно — значит валидно https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/